# Windows 10 File Explorer: batch rename formatting options?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, batch-rename

When Windows 10 batch renames files it uses a format like: "file (1).html".

Is it possible to set the the default for batch renaming to format the files like: "file1.html" to avoid additional characters instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not from Windows Explorer.  You'd want to use PowerShell or a third party program, many of which are free.  Batch renaming is pretty common, so there are plenty of choices.  There isn't a way to change the format for the Windows Explorer way of doing things, though.

If you are not comfortable with PowerShell and don't want to download a virus or malware, then I'll go ahead and recommend [Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/).  It's very popular image modification software and it happens to include batch renaming in its functionality (File -> Batch Conversion/Rename).  In there, you can specify the exact format you want for the renamed files.  And, IrfanView (As well as its plug-ins if you decide you like the image editing part of the software) is 100% free.

Comment: How could this be done with PowerShell?

Comment: As an example, this: Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace “ “,”_” }  That will replace all the spaces in the current directory with underscores.  In your case, you could replace " (" with "" and then replace ")" with nothing as well  (I.e., -NewName {$_.name -replace " (", ""}  For full details, see here: [link]http://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/